# How can I create a Doctrine2 object with foreign key/id set without having that object at hand?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine object (A) and inside that object I have a serialized version of another Doctrine object (B). Then I have a getter on (A) that deserializes the serialized string (for (B)) and recreates the Doctrine object (B) out of it. My problem now is that the serialized object (B) again has relations to two other objects (C, D). At the moment I basically create all the objects needed (C,D) and then recreate (B) and return it in the getter.

My problem with this is that the getter needs access to some repositories or the entity manager in order to get the objects C and D.

Is there a way how I could just set the foreign keys in (B) manually without the need for repositories or the entity manager? That would make the whole setup much easier as I wouldn't need to pass the classes down through all calls that use the getter.

Comment: Might want to rethink your design.  Serialized entities inside of other entities?  Not something that Doctrine normally deals with.  It is possible that an Active Record approach, in which each entity does have access to the database, might suit you better.

Comment: Thanks, Cerad. We are actually coming from an Active Record approach in the past and now trying to get more structured and more separated. Problem is I have a complex billing object holding billing information, address, etc. and when I create invoice objects I want to copy this billing object into the invoice. The goal is to lose the relation to the original billing object and manage the one in the invoice separately. I'm reusing a number of methods also implemented on the original object, so thought about getting around a separate model for the nested entity. Hope that makes it more clear.